# Is there a tense issue in this sentence?

Tags: tenses, questions

The garbage bags slipped from her hands, crashing to the ground.

Comment: No tense problem, but a style problem: another one of those awful gerund phrases ("crashing to the ground") that should really be conjoined with "and": _The garbage bags slipped from her hands **and crashed** to the ground_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word, no.

I presume you are referring to the apparent tense difference between *slipped* and *crashing*.  However, *crashing to the ground* is a [participle phrase](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/particterm.htm) (that is, a verb phrase functioning as an adjective) that modifies the noun, *bags*.  As such it is under no requirement to conform to the tense of the main verb.  As noted on the linked page,

> A present participle attributes a quality of action to the noun, which is viewed as undertaking the action [...]. A past participle views the noun as having undergone the action expressed by the participle[.]

The bags, at the point when they were slipping, were also crashing; Thus the present participle (*crashing*) is called for.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a problem. I think the sentence should read:

> The garbage bags slipped from her hands and crashed to the ground.

Answer (score -2):

There is no tense problem even if it appears there is. This is a very common usage. However, I think *on* would suit better:

> The garbage bags slipped from her hands, crashing **on** the ground.